# Extracting values from TopicPartition - confluent kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

Trying to extract the tuple values from TopicPartition like topic, partition, offset etc. Could not locate a helper method. Added code snippet below

```
from confluent_kafka import DeserializingConsumer

conf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'bootstrap_server',
    <other configurations>
}

consumer = DeserializingConsumer(conf)
deserializing_consumer.subscribe([topic])

while True:
    
    data = deserializing_consumer.poll(10)
    for assignment in deserializing_consumer.assignment():
        print(assignment)
```

The print statement only emits the output like the below, but would like to extract key, values individually. TopicPartition is not iterable as well. Can you please provide some pointers?

```
TopicPartition{topic=test-topic,partition=%I32d,offset=%s,leader_epoch=%s,error=%s}
```

python version 3.11.0

Kafka broker version 2.5.0

confluent-kafka==2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually poll records. The consumer assignment doesn't read data from any topic, it only has partition numbers

See Message object. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#pythonclient-message